# How to Get Last Updated Record with Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel Query Builder to get the last updated record from the database. However, it displays a different `id` with a different `update_date.` The `update_date` is correct, and it shows me last updated_date, but every time I'm getting the first `id.`

```php
$results = DB::table('customer_info as cust_info')
    ->join('client_emp as client_info', 'cust_info.id', '=', 'client_info.cust_id')
    ->select('cust_info.id', DB::raw('MAX(cust_info.updated_at)'))
    ->orderBy('cust_info.id','DESC')
    ->first();
```

In the above query, I write select to get the `id` of last updated record.

```php
->select('cust_info.id', DB::raw('MAX(cust_info.updated_at)'))
```

However, it shows me the last `updated_date` only with the first id from the table every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->first()->id
```

Here you are getting the id of the latest updated record. When you remove the first() method, you will get the whole collection sorted by 'updated_at'